# aws status check failed alarm is not taking the action

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm

I have one instance which always gives the headache of failing system status check which I had to reboot the instance in order to get it running again.

I see that there's an option to `create status check alarm` which I did
I did receive the notification through email + sns as I have set but the instance did not get rebooted that I have to go into ec2 dashboard to reboot manually

[image: create alarm]

Any settings I am not setting correctly or if anyone has other ideas how I can reboot the instance automatically if status check failed?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the recover action on a system status check failure and reboot only works on instance status checks failures. They are distinctly different failures with different causes.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html

I would setup separate alarms for each condition. One for instance status check failure and system level failure, reboot and recover respectively.

Comment: I feel like this should be a feature request to recover(stop/start) an instance based off the `StatusCheckFailed` metric as a recover for both alerts will fix the issue and reduce costs by only needing one alarm

Comment: @mRyan Would definitely appreciate that. Idk why it is the way it is. I'm sure under the hood there's some logic for why.

Comment: Probably worth noting that a reboot and a recover have different behaviors. With a recover, you could end up with a new vm on a different rack (i think). That may not be desirable in some cases.